# Sequência de execução de funções

Tags: java, funções, java-processing

Estou com uma dúvida sobre a sequência de execução de funções. Por exemplo, no código abaixo, porque ele imprime y=2.0 e não y=4.0 e porque imprime w=0.5 e não w=2.2. O y=2.0 entendo que ele busca o valor que estão mais próximo. Até aí tudo bem. Mas porque w=0.5 e não 2.2 que que é o valor da variável global? Existe algum tipo de prioridade de execução?

```
float w = 2.2;
float y = 3.0;
void setup(){
  y = 2.0;
 float x = fn(w + y, y);

 println(x + "," + y + "," + w);
}
float fn(float x, float y){
 w = 0.5;
 y = 4.0;
 return w + x + y;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Começamos na função `setup` definindo o valor de `y` e chamando a função `fn`:

```
float w = 2.2;
float y = 3.0;

void setup(){
  y = 2.0; //alterar o y global
  float x = fn(w + y, y);
//resulta em fn(2.2 + 2.0, 2.0); => fn(4.2, 2.0);
```

Que chama a função `fn` com os valores indicados acima. Essa vai agora definir valores e retornar um resultado:

```
float fn(float x, float y){
  //--------------------^ Parâmetro com nome igual a uma variável global que acaba 
  //                      por esconder essa variável global

  w = 0.5; //alterar o w global
  y = 4.0; //alterar o parametro y da função para 4.0, deixando o y global em 2.0
  return w + x + y; 
//return 0.5 + 4.2 + 4.0 = 8.7
}
```

Note que a instrução que altera o `y` apenas afeta o parâmetro da função e não o `y` global porque o nome é igual.

Depois do retorno fazemos o *print*:

```
println(x + "," + y + "," + w);
//      8,7  ,    2.0  ,   0.5
```

O `w` ficou com `0.5` porque a alteração dentro de `fn` afetou o `w` global, uma vez que não havia nenhum parâmetro da função com o mesmo nome.

---

Nota: Os floats literais devem de levar o `f` na sua inicialização, ficando algo como:

```
float w = 2.2f;
```

Caso contrário serão interpretados como doubles.

Comment: Se eu comentar o y=2.0 logo de pois da função setup(), por que ele não y=4.0 e pega o valor global?

Comment: A função `fn` tem um parametro chamado `y`. Logo qualquer coisa que seja relacionada com `y` dentro dessa função refere o parametro e não o global. O problema tem a ver com o facto de o nome ser igual

Comment: Fiquei com mais uma dúvida sobre esse assunto. Nesse exemplo o método change é inútil? :`void setup() {
  int[] x = {1,5,7,2};
  println(x);
  change(x);
  println(x);
}
void change(int[] a){
  a = new int[]{1,2,3};
}`

Comment: @Jsi83 Nem por isso, atribuir um novo array ao parametro `a` no método `change` não altera o original que estava no método `setup`

Comment: Mas qual a diferença aqui? Porque aqui eu altero o elemento no index 2 e no exemplo acima eu não altero o array? `void setup() {
  int[] x = {1,5,7,2};
  println(x);
  change(x);
  println(x);
}
void change(int[] a){
  a[2] = 9;
}`

Comment: @find83 A diferença está em alterar um elemento numa posição ou atribuir um novo array. `array[posicao] = outrovalor;` versus `array = new int[quantidade]`